# Mongoid : HABTM does not preserve insertion order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having a small issue here. In my project, there's pages who can have multiple settings (there is one Settings object per (user, page)). These settings can reference "inspiration pages".

So my settings schema looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/2020753). The association is not reflected on the `Page` class. The problem is shown at the bottom of the gist : while in the ruby object, the insertion order seems to preserved, it looks like on the database side, it's not.

Any idea what's happening here ?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I want to be sure that it's a bug first, not just something I did wrong, missed, or misunderstood :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I filed an issue on the mongoid tracker, and I got an answer, see https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1813.

Basically, it is too costly to be handle at the level of mongoid, so I have to sort it myself accord to the `inspiration_page_ids` array, which behaves as expected regarding insertion. There's good examples in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/8777d825031196ee) on how to do it.

Comment: For the record I had this need to and here is a code sample on how to do the sorting on ruby side to follow a specific ids array:
`def self.fixed_sort(ids); all.sort_by { |c| ids.index(c.id) || Float::INFINITY }; end`
Add this method on the relation model and then call with: `model.relation.fixed_sort(model.relation_ids)`. This also works with other criteria chained.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bug report about this behavior :

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1705

This Issue is fix on Mongoid 2.4.4

Comment: After seeing this bug report, I updated mongoid -- I was in 2.4.2. But now, in 2.4.6, the problem still is the same, so I opened another issue